# iOS: Find bottom y coordinate of rotated and rounded view

Tags: ios, objective-c, cgaffinetransform, cashapelayer, cgrect

I have a `UIView` with `CALayer` inside. And I try to add `UILabel` directly at the bottom of this layer. But I can't find it's coordinates. On the screenshot v**iew got a blue color, layer - white, label - red**.
The 1st screenshot is how it works and the second one is how it should work.

[image]
[image]
Label position:

```
CGFloat yPos = CGRectGetMaxY(view.frame) + CGRectGetHeight(labelHeight) / 2;
label.center = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(view.frame), yPos);
```

View rotate:

```
view.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(object.tableRotate * M_PI/180);
```

Layer inside view:

```
self.circularLayer.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, CGRectGetWidth(self.bounds), CGRectGetHeight(self.bounds));
```

I'm applying rounded corners with mask:

```
- (void)makeOval
{
    CAShapeLayer *mask = [self shapeMaskLayer];
    CGRect bounds = self.circularLayer.bounds;
    if (!CGRectEqualToRect(mask.frame, bounds)) {
        mask.frame = bounds;
        mask.path = CGPathCreateWithEllipseInRect(bounds, nil);
    }
}

- (CAShapeLayer *)shapeMaskLayer
{
    if (self.circularLayer.mask && [self.circularLayer.mask isKindOfClass:[CAShapeLayer class]]) {
        return (CAShapeLayer *)self.circularLayer.mask;
    } else {
        CAShapeLayer *layer = [CAShapeLayer layer];
        layer.fillColor = [UIColor blackColor].CGColor;
        self.circularLayer.mask = layer;
        return layer;
    }
}
```